# QuickBlox user sign up issue REST API

Tags: php, rest, curl, quickblox

I am following the procedure mentioned in 
http://quickblox.com/developers/Users
so first I get the token by posting curl with this params:

```
Array
(
    [application_id] => 24719
    [auth_key] => PY8EEvrxtPg3sGs
    [timestamp] => 1435915101
    [nonce] => 1435915100
    [signature] => f45bdb40e8cfcf7235502b38586479f83925c6ad
)
```

to https://api.quickblox.com/session.json
and getting response :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [session] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 55965365535c12a58c031d01
            [application_id] => 24719
            [created_at] => 2015-07-03T09:18:29Z
            [device_id] => 0
            [nonce] => 1435915100
            [token] => b913e37d88a0cab296eec6f44643e282d107dd58
            [ts] => 1435915101
            [updated_at] => 2015-07-03T09:18:29Z
            [user_id] => 0
            [id] => 1004
        )

)
```

However, when I try to create a new user account with below params:

```
Array
(
    [login] => prasun1010
    [full_name] => prasun1010
    [custom_data] => I am a boy
    [password] => ssd_p@p_23_1_
    [token] => b913e37d88a0cab296eec6f44643e282d107dd58
    [Version] => 0.1.0
    [website] => http://localhost/xxx/trunk/php/
)
```

to : http://api.quickblox.com/users.json

it is responsing :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [code] => 
    [message] => No data was provided
)
```

Can someone please let me know what wrong I am doing ? Or what should I do to get it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [documentation](http://quickblox.com/developers/Users#User_Sign_Up), your sign up params should be wrapped into 'user' entity. So your new user params should look like:

```
   Array
    (
        [user] => Array 
        (
            [login] => prasun1010
            [full_name] => prasun1010
            [custom_data] => I am a boy
            [password] => ssd_p@p_23_1_
            [token] => b913e37d88a0cab296eec6f44643e282d107dd58
            [Version] => 0.1.0
            [website] => http://localhost/xxx/trunk/php/
        )
    )
```